# For what values of $x$ is the matrix singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

For what values of $x$ is the $3\times 3$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}3-x&2&2\\1&4-x&1\\-2&-4&-1-x\end{pmatrix}$ singular?

This seems to be about eigenvalues.

Comment: if Determinant=0 then its singular so find determinant and equal to zero and find x

Comment: Oh. So this one's really a long way. Thanks.

Comment: yes and also the same values of x are eigenvalues and thats how you find eigenvalues

Comment: Finding the determinant of this matrix is not hard. Use some shortcuts. For example add the second row to the third row and then the second column to the third column. Or something else that give you some zero arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much, friends.